# Display image after taxonomy text with advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom post type called:'activities' and created a taxonomy for it called: 'activity_locations'. I have then added a custom field to the taxonomy for an image using Advanced Custom Fields, this image field is called: 'activity_location_image'

On the single template I have managed to display the taxonomy for the product with the following code:

```
Available in: <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'activity_locations', ' ', ' / ' ); ?>
```

However I need to elaborate on this to add a small image after the taxonomy text. I have tried the following code but it hasn’t worked (nothing is displaying):

```
<?php
$term = get_field('test');
  if( $term ): ?>
  <img src="<?php echo get_field('activity_location_image', $term); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone offer any advice/assistance on how to make this work?

Comment: What does `get_field('test')` return?

Comment: This should return the custom field content for the taxonomy, in this case I have created a field called test which displays in the taxonomy but I can't get the results to show.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still on the single template page, then `get_field()` without a second argument will only be fetching metadata for your current post object, not the related term objects.

If you read the [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) for `get_field()` you'll see that to query for **term** fields you need to use the format

`get_field('field_name', 'taxonomyname_X)`

Where `taxonomyname` would be `activity_locations` and `X` would be the term ID.

Since you want to customize the display and use the data about the terms, you'll have to swap `the_terms()` with `wp_get_post_terms()` which will give you an array of term objects. You can then loop over the array, grabbing the image for each term and outputting the HTML to display the term.